# POST call failing in Angular

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular v.5+ app.  I am trying to implement a POST call in which the user will enter the name of a company, and that name will be written to a Mongo database.

(Since this is the first Angular app I am writing, I am trying to follow closely the outline in the Angular.io Tour of Heroes tutorial.  So if a lot of what I have looks similar to that, that's why.)

My Company object is defined as follows:

```
export class Company {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

My addCompany function, in company.component.ts, looks like this:

```
  addCompany(name: string): void {
    name = name.trim();
    if(!name) { return; }
    this.companyService.addCompany( {name} as Company)
      .subscribe(company => {
        this.companies.push(company);
      });
  }
```

The addCompany function called here, from company.service.ts, looks like this:

```
  addCompany(company: Company): Observable<Company> {
    return this.http.post<Company>(this.addCompanyUrl,company,httpOptions ).pipe(
      tap((company:Company) => console.log(`added company w/ id=${company._id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Company>('addCompany'))
    );
  }
```

And within my API for interacting with the database, my app.post function looks like this:

```
  app.post('/add-company', (req,res) => {
    console.log('name: ' + req.body.name);
    const comp = { name: req.body.name };
    db.collection('companies').insert(comp, (err,result) => {
      if(err) {
        res.send({'error':'An error has occurred.'});
      }
      else {
        res.send({'success':result});
      }
    });
  });
```

The strange thing is this: when I step through using Chrome Dev Tools, I can see the company name is defined within addCompany, but where I have the console.log call in app.post, it says req.body.name is undefined, and so an error occurs.  However, when I use Postman to make a call to app.post directly, the name I send in is defined, and the insert succeeds.

Does anyone see what the problem might be, or what I can try to do differently?

Comment: In your network tab of the dev tools, do you see the body of the post request? Are you setting the header `content-type: 'application/json'` in your httpOptions?

Comment: I am setting the content type to application/json.

Comment: And you see the body being sent in the network tab of the dev tools?

Comment: Yes.  I see  the company name I entered being sent, and a success message with the MongoDB id of the record created.  But when I look in Mongo, that record has a name of 'null'.

Comment: what's app.post? can't really see addCompany function gets in there though.

Comment: app.post() comes from Express.

Comment: so how was your express configured? would be nice to include that part of code in your question as well

Comment: @woodykiddy Can you be more specific about what you want to know?  I can look that up in my code, but I don't really know what you're asking.

Comment: @Phil i meant the code in your app.config().

Comment: I don't have one.  I'll look into that.  Is there anything specific I should be looking at/for?

Answer (score 0):

I notice you are using

```
 <this.http.post<company>
```

are you trying to receive the res.send back in a different format then json? 
If you are using httpclient it will return a Json format as the standard.
You can then use:

let key of result to iterate over the data, or use console.log (JSON.stringify(result)) to output the data.

Comment: It's supposed to be in JSON, but I don't know if it is or not.  It always looks like its undefined.

Comment: More to the point, the req is what looks like it's incorrect, not the res.  Something is going wrong before the res is even generated.

Comment: Did you try without <company>

Comment: did you console.log the result of addcompany function, maybe something goes wrong there or in the pipe. You are doing {name} as Company! not sure wha that does, is this an alias? Shouldn’t company be a array of some sort that has a key name in it?